# Shaking Object With Swinging/Tilting Effect in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, effect, tween, shake

I have an image of a bottle on the stage. I want to have it so that the user can click and drag the bottle around. I want the bottle to sway as it's dragged so tilt and rotate as if it's being pulled back and forth. I've Googled this and found nothing. How can I achieve this effect through code?

So far I've created a timer that tracks a start and end point during drag, calculates distance travelled to get a rough idea of speed and direction and then rotates the bottle within a range of 120 degrees using the Tween class (and then bounce back to 0 after). It's close but not quite as fluid looking as I'd like.. I feel like I need some kind of custom easing function but I'm not great with this type of math.

```
function distanceTimerBeat(e:TimerEvent):void
{//speed detection beat timer
distCounter++;
if(!distSwitch)
{
    startX = product.x;
    startY = product.y;
    distSwitch = true;
}
else
{
    endX = product.x;
    endY = product.y;
    distSwitch = false;
    var newDistance = calculateDistance();
    setRotation();
    //trace('>> ('+distCounter+') distance travelled = '+newDistance);
    //produceNewFirework()
    }   
}

function calculateDistance():Number
{//returns distance travelled over beat timer intervals

var rawDistance = (( startX - endX ) * (startX - endX )) + ((startY - endY ) * (startY - endY ));
var distance = Math.sqrt( rawDistance);
var xDistance = startX - endX;
if(xDistance < 0)
{
    speedDirection = 'right';
    directionModifier = -1;
}
else if(xDistance > 0)
{
    speedDirection = 'left';
    directionModifier = 1;
}

//trace('>> going '+speedDirection+' at '+xDistance);
return distance;
}

function setRotation():void
{ //once start & end values are detected, check speed and set the rotation.

var curSpeed = calculateDistance();

if(curSpeed > 4)
{
    tweenLock = false;


    var speedPercent = curSpeed/maxSpeed * 100;

    var rotationDegree = (speedPercent*120)/300;
    var newRotation = directionModifier*rotationDegree;


    var reversePercent = 100 - speedPercent;
    var tweenSpeedModifier = (speedPercent/100);
    //trace(tweenSpeedModifier*1);

    //if(!tweenLock)
        //rotationTween = null;

        if(rotationTween) rotationTween.stop();
        rotationTween = new Tween(product, "rotation", Strong.easeInOut, product.rotation, newRotation, 0.25, true);
        //rotationTween.resume();
        rotationTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, resetProductTween);
        //trace('speed percet = '+speedPercent);

}
else
{
    //tweenLock = true;
}
}

function resetProductTween(e:TweenEvent)
{//after the product rotates, snap it back to it's original position.
tweenLock = false;
if(!tweenLock)
{
    rotationTween = new Tween(product, "rotation", Strong.easeOut, product.rotation, 0, 0.75, true);
    rotationTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, tweenUnlock);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-trigonometry-for-flash-game-developers--active-4458

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, calculateAngle);

var myAtan2:Number;

function calculateAngle(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    myAtan2 = Math.atan2(e.stageY - mCircle.y, e.stageX - mCircle.x);
    trace(myAtan2);
}
```